# reverse for account_login not found in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying o add to my Django project a registration view from the [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) package.

I added the view to my **urls.py** file but i keep getting the following error:

```
Reverse for 'account_login' not found. 'account_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here is how i added the view to my urls:

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/", SignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
]
```

I don't really understand what am i missing when importing the view, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to include the following pattern in urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```